# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Ticket_Tour_TourID' on table 'Ticket' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

My `DbContext` looks like this:

```
public partial class YalcomniaDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public YalcomniaDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hotel> Hotel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OfficeBranch> OfficeBranch { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ticket> Ticket { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tour> Tour { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicle { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

My ticket model looks like this:

```
public class Ticket : BaseEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // Relational Properties
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Tour Tour { get; set; }
}
```

My tour model looks like this:

```
public class Tour : BaseEntity
{
    public string TourName { get; set; }
    public string TourDescription { get; set; }
    public string TourType { get; set; }
    public string TourGuide { get; set; }
    public int TourPrice { get; set; }
    public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }
    public Employee vehicleDriver { get; set; }
}
```

But whenever I try to update my database I got this error message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Ticket_Tour_TourID' on table 'Ticket' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This is whole error in the log:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Ticket] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Description] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [Title] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] int NOT NULL,
    [HotelID] int NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] int NOT NULL,
    [TourID] int NOT NULL,
    [VehicleID] int NOT NULL,
    [Status] int NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Ticket] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ticket_Customer_CustomerID] FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [Customer] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ticket_Employee_EmployeeID] FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [Employee] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ticket_Hotel_HotelID] FOREIGN KEY ([HotelID]) REFERENCES [Hotel] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ticket_Tour_TourID] FOREIGN KEY ([TourID]) REFERENCES [Tour] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ticket_Vehicle_VehicleID] FOREIGN KEY ([VehicleID]) REFERENCES [Vehicle] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I simply don't know what to do, can anyone help?

I tried a little bit to prevent cascading, but I don't exactly know how to do it, so it always failed in different ways.

Comment: There's an overwhelming amount of questions on this exception. Please try to find them.

Comment: The first thing is to find the cascade cycle in your model, which is not always the place reported by the EF. Looking at code you've shown, most likely it is caused by something in the `BaseEntity`, like `CreatedBy` or `ModifiedBy` pointing to `ApplicationUser`. In general, follow references (or collections) until you find 2 paths leading to one and the same entity. Actually as I see, both `Ticket` and `Tour` have reference to `Employee`, so here is your cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to have one-to-many relationship between tickets and tours, right? One Tour => Many Tickets.
First problem - you don't have "many" relationship on the tour side. You should have

```
public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
```

Second problem wouldn't prevent you from generating SQL, but it's a good practice to have ID in the Ticket class:

```
public int TourId { get; set; }
```

Finally, sometimes it doesn't work for some unexplainable reason although it *should* work for you. In this case, you do what the error says you should do. In your DbContext class you explicitly specify ON DELETE action:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>(entity =>
     {
         entity.HasOne(d => d.Tour)
         .WithMany(p => p.Tickets)
         .HasForeignKey(d => d.TourId)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
     }
}
```

Only put this as last resort.